# Running a exe file (import.io) through PHP in Ubuntu

Tags: php, import.io

I need to call an installed tool - Import.io using PHP in Ubuntu. Whenever I click on the PHP button it should navigate to import.io tool installed in the system and open import.io. how can I do it?

Comment: Just seen your later question on this. Why don't you wish to use the API? Do you expect a desktop application to pop up when clicking on HTML button in a PHP web app? (That will only work locally).

Comment: Dats what i need actually. to run it locally, Using Api i can only call previously crawled data from import.io, if i can call the aap locally by php i can be able to crawl new set of data from import.io, dats wat i m aiming to

Answer (score 4):

Files ending in `.exe` are Windows binaries, and won't run on Ubuntu natively. You might be able to get it to run on Wine, a Windows emulator for Linux.

However, since this is import.io, I suspect it would be much easier, and much more reliable, to call their API instead. You can do this with any HTTP library, such as cURL, Guzzle, Pest, etc.