# Running import.io app through PHP without an API

Tags: php, import.io

I need to call an App- Import.io without the API option available through php. On clicking the submit in PHP, it should navigate to the app import.io and should run it. How can I do it?

Comment: tried with api but not getting expected result, even tried calliing import.io by browser but it wont perform unless its through aap.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running a exe file (import.io) through PHP in Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028525/running-a-exe-file-import-io-through-php-in-ubuntu)